# Loop through dependent list selections and print out

Tags: vba, list, drop-down-menu, dependencies

I have a data validation drop down list with 77 different selections I need for a monthly report. I am a vba newbie but I found a code that prints out the currently selected option in a folder, from selection cell A1 (aka"Strategy"). What i would like to do is add a loop through code that automatically prints all different selections to seperate pdfs into the same folder. My current code is:

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()

Dim ws                    As Worksheet
Dim myFile                As Variant
Dim strFile               As String
Dim sFolder               As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = ws.Range("A1").Value & " Strategy Output " & ws.Range("J1").Value

sFolder = GetFolder()
If sFolder = "" Then
    MsgBox "No folder selected. Code will terminate."
    Exit Sub
End If
myFile = sFolder & "\" & strFile

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=2

exitHandler:
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
Resume exitHandler
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
dlg.Title = "Select folder to save PDFs"
If dlg.Show = -1 Then
    GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If
End Function
```

The code I have found on previous pages of this site for the loop through of the list is as follows, but i keep getting a run time 1004 error on it (Application defined). Does anyone know why?

```
Private Sub Loop_Through_List()

Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range

Set DV_Cell = Range("Strategy")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
    DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
    Call PDFActiveSheet
Next
End Sub
```